# How to restart vim from a bash script?

Tags: bash, vim

I want to restart vim from a bash script so that vim picks up out-of-band changes.  I almost have it working but I am stuck trying to determine what to use to launch vim.

Here's what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
local servername=$(vim --serverlist)
[ -n "$servername" ] && {
  vim --servername "$servername" --remote-send '<C-\><C-N>:mks! _session.vim<CR>:wqa<CR>'
  vim -S _session.vim
  sleep 1
  rm _session.vim
}
```

The problem is the `vim` called by the script is the very obsolete system vim at `/usr/bin/vim`, not "my" vim which is an alias to `mvim -v` (where `mvim` is the launch script which comes with MacVim).

This has two unfortunate consequences: (1) the system vim doesn't recognise `--serverlist`; (2) even if it did my script would subsequently launch the wrong vim.

What's the best way to invoke the vim on my path?

Comment: Can't you just replace `vim` with `mvim -v` as you say?

Comment: Well that would work for me, on this particular machine, but I'd prefer a portable solution.

Comment: What are these out-of-band changes? Changes to files you are editing? If so see `:h 'autoread'`. Changes in your vim files or plugins? Use `:source` or use something like [Scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) to reload a plugin. You update vim while using vim?

Comment: @PeterRincker They are adding/updating/removing plugins.  It's simpler to restart Vim afterwards than deal with all the edge cases that come when trying to reload plugins in-process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The default vim is never built with `+clientserver` so the portability you are afraid to loose was never there to begin with.
2. Aliases are not expanded in bash scripts so your script won't see `mvim -v` if you don't tell it explicitly to use that. Furthermore, your `vim` is an *alias* so it is not in your `PATH`.
3. You could define an environment variable somewhere near the top of your script and use it instead of `vim`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   VIM='/path/to/mvim'

   "$VIM" -v whatever
   ```

   Or turn your alias into a proper script.

   Or, maybe, place `mvim` earlier in your `PATH` and call `mvim -v` explicitly.

Comment: 1. Oh.  2. Good to know.  3. Looks like the best bet.  Thanks!